# Can we change places of the past simple and past continuous? Is it always idiomatic?

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

**Can we change places of the past simple and past continuous? Is it always idiomatic?**

> I was walking home when I met Dan.
>
> I met Dan when I was walking home.
>
> When I met Dan, I was walking home.
>
> When I was walking home, I met Dan.

If I understand right, the most popular version is the first one. **Is it possible to say when each version is more appropriate than another one?** For example, the third version is often used in written stories.

Comment: It all depends on which bit of information you want to emphasise. For example, No 3 seems to assume that the reader already knows that you met Dan, and explains just when it happened. (1) and (4) set the scene (walking home, perhaps a daily routine) and announce that something unexpected happened.

Comment: There is no "most popular version".

Comment: @KateBunting, If I understand right, (2) and (3) mean the same thing as it was in your example - "the reader already knows that you met Dan, and explains just when it happened." Right?

Comment: Depending on the context, they might all be good, or only some. There's no definitive answer about the best one just on their own.

Comment: No, not necessarily.  (2) could be an answer to the question "When did you meet Dan?", or it could be a simple statement, with less of a suggestion that the meeting was unexpected than (1) and (4) give.